# how to get go net/http/client connection info

Tags: go, net-http

The go official library provides net/http/client which internally implements a thread-safe connection pool. I want to query the current connection pool status: how many connections, how many are idle, etc. during the program running process

Comment: This information is not exposed.

Answer (score -1):

Although this information is not exposed by the underlying structure, similar functionality can be achieved using external dependencies such as https://github.com/mwitkow/go-conntrack

For example, [Prometheus code](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/cmd/prometheus/main.go) contains the following:

```
// Monitor outgoing connections on default transport with conntrack.
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).DialContext = conntrack.NewDialContextFunc(
        conntrack.DialWithTracing(),
)
```